# How do replenish game currency in intervals in my iphone app.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm making a game app in X Code. The users win and lose "coins" as they play. I understand that Apple requires that you make sure they eventually get more currency for free if they run out. I am going to have in IAP. However I want to put in some kind of time or other method to give them say 100 additional coins every day. So that if they run out they come back and will have a little more currency to play.

I'm very new and if anyone can suggest a simple way to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Currently I store the currency in a long long variable called "coins". I am also using NSUserDefalts to store the amount of "coins". I am going to use that for the IAP.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the last time that you have given the user his free coins along with the remaining coins in the user defaults. Whenever you check the remaining "balance" of the coins, look at that additional variable, and compare it to the current time. If the difference is greater than 24 hours, give the user additional coins, and store the new value in the defaults.

Comment: Thanks that sounds pretty good but here's where my inexperience will show. How do I deal with the time, meaning how do I check and store time. Right now I am just storing a number value for the coins.

Comment: @Herbie999 Call `NSDate *now = [NSDate date]` to obtain the current time. Call `NSTimeInterval diff = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:storedTime]` to calculate the time difference. `diff` is the number of seconds; compare it to `24*60*60` to see if 24 hours have passed since the last free recharge.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight's suggestions are very good, but you should never use 24*60*60 seconds when you mean a calendar day, because calendar days are not always 24 hours. I learned this the hard way with a published app that was struck down by a daylight saving time transition. I found the Performing Calendar Calculations session from [WWDC 2011](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/) very helpful.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks for all the help! You wrote whenever I check the remaining balance of the coins. Would that be something that happens when the app opens? I have a variable called "coins" that stores the value. I put in NSUserDefaults but I added them under a IBAction buttonPressed, which is also when all the other calaculations, checking for matches and adding or subtracting coins happens. Something needs to be running periodically to check values stored in NSUserDefaults maybe? But not dependent on the buttonePressed action? I'm sensing something is missing from my app!? lol

Comment: @Herbie999 There's probably a point in your app where you show the number of available coins to the user. This happens when the app becomes active, and also at the moments when coins get spent. You do not need to read user defaults each time: you can calculate the next "replenishment" time on start-up, and check if the current time is greater than the time when you have to credit the user. If you would like to update the number as soon as the coins appear on user's account, you could add a simple `NSTimer` job running, say, once per minute, to do additional checking.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank you that's starting to make sense and doesn't sound as daunting. I am going to try that code you included above. Does this mean the time would only pass when the app is open? If that's the case I should probably make it less than 24 hrs. Thanks for your help!!!!!

Comment: @Herbie999 You are welcome! Note that since you store the timestamp of the last "credit" as the actual time, the time between credits would pass regardless of whether or not your application is running, or even whether or not the device is powered up. Only updates would be dependent on the state of your app: if it's not running, the next update would happen only on the next start-up. You could get fancy and figure out if several days have passed, to credit 100 coins per day.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Hi! Not sure if you'll get this but I'm a little stuck here again. How are all these actions supposed to be triggered. Is it a viewDidLoad method or what? I am not sure where to put this in my code. Right now I have a coins variable, that changes depending on if things match up after a person pushes a SPIN button kind of like a slot machine. Then I use if statements to determine what should be added or subtracted from the "coins" and a UILabel to display this number. Where exactly would this code go and what would it look like. Sorry I'm just really new! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Herbie999 I would put a check in the `viewDidAppear` and in the code that processes the spin button (make a method and call it from both places). I would also make an `NSTimer`, start it in `ViewDidLoad`, and do additional checks periodically to make the app more dynamic.

Comment: Hey forgot to write back, but it all worked like a charm! Thanks again!